# How to use cpplint code style checking with CMake?

Tags: cmake, cpplint

The only online resources I have found are the CMake documentation on `CMAKE_<LANG>_CPPLINT` (link [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CPPLINT.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_CPPLINT)) and this example (link [here](https://blog.kitware.com/static-checks-with-cmake-cdash-iwyu-clang-tidy-lwyu-cpplint-and-cppcheck/)), but I cannot figure out how to actually use it inside a CMakeLists.txt file.
I tried the example provided, but I can't make it work. FYI, I installed cpplint as explained [here](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint).

As of now, I can run the cpplint python script inside CMakeLists.txt using this CMake command:

```
execute_process(COMMAND cpplint path/To/File/To/Analyse.cpp)
```

However, I am pretty sure that this is not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recommended way to use static analysis tools with CMake was presented in Daniel Pffeifer's "Effective Cmake" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLopVhns4Zs&amp=&t=77m13s).

You can either define it when calling `cmake`, eg.:

```
cmake "-DCMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT=cpplint" ..
```

or put it into `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT "cpplint")
```

Recommended option is the first one (we shouldn't define in a project what isn't a project requirement).

CMake will call `cpplint` for each file it compiles. You can pass extra arguments after semicolon (e.g. `-DCMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT=cpplint;--linelength=100`).

---

Downsides of this method:

1. Errors count will not get accumulated (because `cpplint` is invoked for each file separately).
2. It will not check header files (as opposed to what D. Pffeifer says in his presentation, include files are not being scanned by `cpplint`).

---

Note that you can use other static analysis tools the same way:

- Clan Tidy `"-DCMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY=/usr/bin/clang-tidy-3.9;-checks=*"`
- CppCheck `"-DCMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK=/usr/bin/cppcheck;--std=c++11"`
- IWYU `"-DCMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE=/usr/bin/iwyu;--transitive_includes_only"`
- LWYU `cmake -DCMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE=TRUE`
- clazy

Some of them will require "compilation database" (`set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)`).

Answer (score 1):

I failed to use `CMAKE_<LANG>_CPPLINT` to check code style.

I make it by using `add_custom_target`.

1. download [cpplint.py](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/cpplint/cpplint.py)
2. then download [cpplint.cmake](https://github.com/acado/acado/blob/master/cmake/CppLint.cmake) or write yourselt.

Suppose that there is a source code directory named *src* in your project, code those statements into your *CMakeLists.txt*.

```
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src src)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}) #I put cpplint.cmake in $CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR
include(cpplint)

add_style_check_target(phoenix-cpplint "${src}")
```

Note:

1. you should pass the whole list, so use [`"${src}"` instead of `${src}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5253591/5393174).
2. By default nothing depends on the custom target, see [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html).

If there's still some problem, [debug your CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22803821/5393174).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How to make sure that this custom target is run after all the other application targets?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same problem.

I tried it with CMake 3.10.2 and the comment by user2449761 is still true. Using set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT "cpplint") still does not check any header files.

The answer by kgbook does not work anymore, since aux_source_directory does not list the header files. You can, however, use

```
get_target_property(src staticcodecheck SOURCES)
```

That will give you all the non-system headers. The rest can be kept the same. As for running cpplint at a specific time, you might try

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET}
    PRE_BUILD
...
```

That will replace add_custom_target(${TARGET_NAME}... in his cpplint.cmake.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I am running `cpplint` on all files in the `src` directory for a project.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*")
add_custom_command(TARGET target PRE_BUILD COMMAND cpplint ${SRC_FILES})
```

This runs every time, it fails the build when there are `cpplint` issues, and it runs on all files in the `src` directory. You may also want to consider adding `cpplint` specific arguments to the command, such as `--quiet` or `--extensions` for example.