# How to integrate CPPLINT into CMake and also scan header files?

Tags: c++, cmake, cpplint

I can get cpplint working with CMake quite easily, but as is explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582604/how-to-use-cpplint-code-style-checking-with-cmake), it only scans the compilation files (e.g. .cpp, .cc); it doesn't scan the header files even though they're being included in the project. The question above also has some other answers that provide a potential solution through hacks, but is there no integrated way to do this by now?

All I had to do to get cpplint to work work with my project was add the flag on the first cmake call:
`cmake "-DCMAKE_CXX_CPPLINT=cpplint"`

I am using the Ninja generator on Windows.  My `add_library` command includes both .cpp and .h files, but I only get errors for the .cpp files.

Comment: Can you provide the CMake code showing the cpplint integration you have so far, so we can understand what you have and what may need to be changed or added?

Comment: Done.  All I had to do was pass the flag, but I added that anyway for clarification.

Comment: I'm actually looking at an alternative of using clang-tidy instead of cpplint.  clang-tidy seems to analyze header files it encounters in source files and it has has google style rules as an option to enable.  Hopefully there isn't too much missing from what cpplint covers.

Comment: For me, clang-tidy seems to cover more than cpplint, but there were still things in cpplint that were not in clang-tidy. My clang-tidy is kind of old though, so maybe a recent version would be better.