# Problem using Qt4 with find_package of CMake, inside a macro

Tags: cmake, qt4, cmake-language

I have defined the following macro in CMake (version 3.10):

```
macro(configureQt4 requiredVersion selectedPackages)
    message(STATUS "selectedPackages: ${selectedPackages}")
    find_package(Qt4 ${requiredVersion} COMPONENTS ${selectedPackages} REQUIRED ) 
endmacro()
```

Now, when I tried to call the macro in the following way, I get an error:

```
set(SelectedQt4Packages "QtCore QtNetwork")
configureQt4( 4.8 ${SelectedQt4Packages})
```

The error reported is:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QTCORE QTNETWORK_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTCORE
  QTNETWORK_LIBRARY) (found suitable version "4.8.7", minimum required is
  "4.8")
```

If I call `find_package()` in the following way inside the macro, it works!

```
find_package(Qt4 ${requiredVersion} COMPONENTS QtCore QtNetwork REQUIRED )
```

But I need to use it by setting a variable as discussed earlier. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a list variable in CMake, you can achieve this by excluding the quotes:

```
set(SelectedQt4Packages QtCore QtNetwork)
```

Using quotes like this `"QtCore QtNetwork"` simply creates a string with a space between the two component names, which is likely not what you intend.

Now, you can pass the `SelectedQt4Packages` list variable to your macro, but be sure to surround it with quotes (as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5253591/3987854)):

```
set(SelectedQt4Packages QtCore QtNetwork)
configureQt4( 4.8 "${SelectedQt4Packages}")
```

Comment: Yeah this answer is much better. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is because CMake expects a **list** of components. That is, a string where each item is separated by a `;`. If you instead do `set(SelectedQt4Packages "QtCore;QtNetwork")` and change the call to `configureQt4( 4.8 "${SelectedQt4Packages}")` (note the double quotes), it should work as expected.

**Edit**: A cleaner solution would be to simply convert the argument to a list inside the macro:

```
# Now we can set selectedPackages to either "QtCore QtNetwork" or "QtCore;QtNetwork", both will work.
macro(configureQt4 requiredVersion selectedPackages)
    message(STATUS "selectedPackages: ${selectedPackages}")
    string(REPLACE " " ";" _selectedQtPackages ${selectedPackages})
    find_package(Qt4 ${requiredVersion} COMPONENTS ${_selectedQtPackages} REQUIRED )
endmacro()
```